# Function to select from columns pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have this test table in pandas dataframe

```
   Leaf_category_id  session_id  product_id
0               111           1         987
3               111           4         987
4               111           1         741
1               222           2         654
2               333           3         321
```

[image]

what i want is

```
for leaf_category_id 111:
```

the result should be.

```
 session_id   product_id
 1            987,741
 4            987
```

Similarly can i define a function that does the same for all the leaf_category id's, my table contains more rows, it was just a snapshot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with apply `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Leaf_category_id':[111,111,111,222,333],
                   'session_id':[1,4,1,2,3],
                   'product_id':[987,987,741,654,321]}, 
                   columns =['Leaf_category_id','session_id','product_id'])

print (df)                   
   Leaf_category_id  session_id  product_id
0               111           1         987
1               111           4         987
2               111           1         741
3               222           2         654
4               333           3         321


print (df[df.Leaf_category_id == 111]
            .groupby('session_id')['product_id']
            .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))))
session_id
1    987,741
4        987
Name: product_id, dtype: object
```

EDIT by comment:

```
print (df.groupby(['Leaf_category_id','session_id'])['product_id']
         .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
         .reset_index())
   Leaf_category_id  session_id product_id
0               111           1    987,741
1               111           4        987
2               222           2        654
3               333           3        321
```

Or if need for each unique value in `Leaf_category_id` `DataFrame`:

```
for i in df.Leaf_category_id.unique():
    print (df[df.Leaf_category_id == i] \
                .groupby('session_id')['product_id'] \
                .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))) \
                .reset_index())

   session_id product_id
0           1    987,741
1           4        987
   session_id product_id
0           2        654
   session_id product_id
0           3        321
```

Comment: Similarly can i define a function that does the same for all the leaf_category id's

Comment: getting error **TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int64 found**

Comment: what is df.dtypes?

Comment: Leaf_category_id    int64
 ,session_id          int64
product_id          int64,
,dtype: object

Comment: Its working now :) thanks @jezrael.  can i define a function and create a loop so that it does the same for all the leaf categories automatically

Comment: Sorry, give me a sec.

Comment: What is desired output? For each `Leaf_category_id` one `DataFrame` ? Or need one dataframe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128058/discussion-between-s-ringne-and-jezrael).