# create a bigram from a column in pandas df

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

i have this test table in pandas dataframe

```
   Leaf_category_id  session_id  product_id
0               111           1         987
3               111           4         987
4               111           1         741
1               222           2         654
2               333           3         321
```

this is the extension of my previous question, which was answered by @jazrael.
[view answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587902/function-to-select-from-columns-pandas-df/40587934#40587934)

so after getting the values in product_id column as(just an assumption, little different from the output of my previous question,

```
   |product_id               |
   ---------------------------
   |111,987,741,34,12        |
   |987,1232                 |
   |654,12,324,465,342,324   |
   |321,741,987              |
   |324,654,862,467,243,754  |
   |6453,123,987,741,34,12   |
```

and so on,
i want to create a new column, in which all the values in a row should be made as a bigram with its next one, and the last no. in the row combined with the first one,for example:

```
   |product_id               |Bigram
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |111,987,741,34,12        |(111,987),**(987,741)**,(741,34),(34,12),(12,111)
   |987,1232                 |(987,1232),(1232,987)
   |654,12,324,465,342,32    |(654,12),(12,324),(324,465),(465,342),(342,32),(32,654)
   |321,741,987              |(321,741),**(741,987)**,(987,321)
   |324,654,862              |(324,654),(654,862),(862,324)
   |123,987,741,34,12        |(123,987),(987,741),(34,12),(12,123)
```

ignore the **( i'll tell you later on why i starred that)

the code to achive the bigram is

```
for i in df.Leaf_category_id.unique(): 
    print (df[df.Leaf_category_id == i].groupby('session_id')['product_id'].apply(lambda x: list(zip(x, x[1:]))).reset_index())
```

from this df, i want to consider the bigram column and make one more column named as frequency, which gives me frequency of bigram occured.

> Note* : (987,741) and (741,987) are to be considered as same and one dublicate entry should be removed and thus frequency of  (987,741) should be 2.
>   similar is the case with (34,12) it occurs two times, so frequency should be 2

```
   |Bigram
   ---------------
   |(111,987),
   |**(987,741)**
   |(741,34)
   |(34,12)
   |(12,111)
   |**(741,987)**
   |(987,321)
   |(34,12)
   |(12,123)
```

Final Result should be.

```
   |Bigram       | frequency |
   --------------------------
   |(111,987)    |  1 
   |(987,741)    |  2
   |(741,34)     |  1
   |(34,12)      |  2
   |(12,111)     |  1
   |(987,321)    |  1
   |(12,123)     |  1
```

i am hoping to find answer here, please help me, i have elaborated it as much as possible.

Comment: How do you want the frequencies stored?  In a single row, the `Bigram` column will contain multiple tuples, so there will be multiple frequencies.

Comment: @James :each tuples in a row should be made as a new row, as shown in second last table. and then if there are duplicate tables, as i mentioned,the frequency should be changed accordingly

Comment: So `Bigram` and `frequency` are in a separate data frame?

Comment: @James: only bigram is in the df, you will get it by the code i posted.
and i want to create a new column named **frequency**
which counts the occurances of individual bigrams.

Comment: @jezrael Could you take a look on this problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("data.csv")
#consecutive
grouped_consecutive_product_ids = df.groupby(['Leaf_category_id','session_id'])['product_id'].apply(lambda x: [tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in zip(x,x[1:])]).reset_index()

df1=pd.DataFrame(grouped_consecutive_product_ids)
s=df1.product_id.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).unstack()
df2=pd.DataFrame(s.reset_index(level=0,drop=True)).dropna()
df2.rename(columns = {0:'Bigram'}, inplace = True)
df2["freq"] = df2.groupby('Bigram')['Bigram'].transform('count')
bigram_frequency_consecutive = df2.drop_duplicates(keep="first").sort_values("Bigram").reset_index()
del bigram_frequency_consecutive["index"]
```

for combinations (all possible bi-grams)

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("data.csv")
#combinations
grouped_combination_product_ids = df.groupby(['Leaf_category_id','session_id'])['product_id'].apply(lambda x: [tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in combinations(x,2)]).reset_index()

df1=pd.DataFrame(grouped_combination_product_ids)
s=df1.product_id.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).unstack()
df2=pd.DataFrame(s.reset_index(level=0,drop=True)).dropna()
df2.rename(columns = {0:'Bigram'}, inplace = True)
df2["freq"] = df2.groupby('Bigram')['Bigram'].transform('count')
bigram_frequency_combinations = df2.drop_duplicates(keep="first").sort_values("Bigram").reset_index()
del bigram_frequency_combinations["index"]
```

where `data.csv` contains

```
Leaf_category_id,session_id,product_id
0,111,1,111
3,111,4,987
4,111,1,741
1,222,2,654
2,333,3,321
5,111,1,87
6,111,1,34
7,111,1,12
8,111,1,987
9,111,4,1232
10,222,2,12
11,222,2,324
12,222,2,465
13,222,2,342
14,222,2,32
15,333,3,321
16,333,3,741
17,333,3,987
18,333,3,324
19,333,3,654
20,333,3,862
21,222,1,123
22,222,1,987
23,222,1,741
24,222,1,34
25,222,1,12
```

The resultant `bigram_frequency_consecutive` will be

```
         Bigram  freq
0      (12, 34)     2
1     (12, 324)     1
2     (12, 654)     1
3     (12, 987)     1
4     (32, 342)     1
5      (34, 87)     1
6     (34, 741)     1
7     (87, 741)     1
8    (111, 741)     1
9    (123, 987)     1
10   (321, 321)     1
11   (321, 741)     1
12   (324, 465)     1
13   (324, 654)     1
14   (324, 987)     1
15   (342, 465)     1
16   (654, 862)     1
17   (741, 987)     2
18  (987, 1232)     1
```

The resultant `bigram_frequency_combinations` will be

```
           Bigram  freq
0      (12, 32)     1
1      (12, 34)     2
2      (12, 87)     1
3     (12, 111)     1
4     (12, 123)     1
5     (12, 324)     1
6     (12, 342)     1
7     (12, 465)     1
8     (12, 654)     1
9     (12, 741)     2
10    (12, 987)     2
11    (32, 324)     1
12    (32, 342)     1
13    (32, 465)     1
14    (32, 654)     1
15     (34, 87)     1
16    (34, 111)     1
17    (34, 123)     1
18    (34, 741)     2
19    (34, 987)     2
20    (87, 111)     1
21    (87, 741)     1
22    (87, 987)     1
23   (111, 741)     1
24   (111, 987)     1
25   (123, 741)     1
26   (123, 987)     1
27   (321, 321)     1
28   (321, 324)     2
29   (321, 654)     2
30   (321, 741)     2
31   (321, 862)     2
32   (321, 987)     2
33   (324, 342)     1
34   (324, 465)     1
35   (324, 654)     2
36   (324, 741)     1
37   (324, 862)     1
38   (324, 987)     1
39   (342, 465)     1
40   (342, 654)     1
41   (465, 654)     1
42   (654, 741)     1
43   (654, 862)     1
44   (654, 987)     1
45   (741, 862)     1
46   (741, 987)     3
47   (862, 987)     1
48  (987, 1232)     1
```

in the above case it groups by both

Comment: Very nice answer,  +1

Comment: @Mr. A  what's the difference  bigram_frequency_consecutive and bigram_frequency_combinations?

Comment: in `bigram_frequency_consecutive`  if a group has product ids `[27,35,99]` then you get bi-grams  `[(27,35),(35,99)]`  where as bi-gram formed by combination's are `[(27,35),(27,99),(35,99)]` if you are doing any kind of product purchase analysis you should be using bi-gram combination's. Since I don't know exact use-case I gave both solutions where first one is as per code snippet given by you and second solution is what mostly needed.

Comment: @Mr.A i could see that you have used for loop while coding, my dataset is  very very large(>1Gb), so looping would cost my computation time.
Can i define a function and get the same result?

Comment: @SRingne I have made changes as requested by you please check it.

Comment: @Mr. A , yeah, awesome sir, just for a confirmation, `grouped_consecutive_product_ids` iterates through all the **Leaf_category id** right, what if, i want to do the same steps for only one Leaf_category id?

Comment: @SRingne let's say you need to do for only *Leaf_category_id == 111* then you should do so `grouped_consecutive_product_ids = df[df.Leaf_category_id == 111].groupby(['Leaf_category_id','session_id'])['product_id'].apply(lambda x: [tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in zip(x,x[1:])]).reset_index()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128220/discussion-between-s-ringne-and-mr-a).

Comment: @Mr.A Please check 'discussion in chat'

Answer (score 2):

We are going to pull out the values from `product_id`, create `bigrams` that are sorted and thus deduplicated, and count them to get the frequency, and then populate a data frame.

```
from collections import Counter

# assuming your data frame is called 'df'

bigrams = [list(zip(x,x[1:])) for x in df.product_id.values.tolist()]
bigram_set = [tuple(sorted(xx) for x in bigrams for xx in x]
freq_dict = Counter(bigram_set)
df_freq = pd.DataFrame([list(f) for f in freq_dict], columns=['bigram','freq'])
```

Comment: when i am running** freq_dict = Counter(bigram_set)**
i am gettin this error: **unhashable type: 'list'**

Comment: the `tuple` function should have taken care of that

Comment: type(bigram_set) = list.

Comment: freq_dict = Counter(bigram_set) its giving me error.  unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Also your code runs for only one Leaf_category_id.

i got a solution from @jazrael which works for 'i' leaf_category id's can you modify your code too :  `for i in df.Leaf_category_id.unique():` 

`print (df[df.Leaf_category_id == i].groupby('session_id')['product_id']`
`.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x, x[1:]))).reset_index())`