# Frequency of a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
a = [(['7', '8'], ['4', '7'],['3', '4'],['3', '8'],['4', '8'],...............['3','4'])]
```

I want to create 2 columns which give me the frequency of the tuples in the list. For example:

```
bigram      frequency
['7','8']     2
['4','7']     3
['3', '4']    6
```

and so on.

And also, consider entries like `['7','8']` and `['8','7']` the same (duplicates). The only one entry should be in the column and frequency should be added to that.

I was trying to use

```
from collections import counter
```

and do some loop over it, but I was getting error as:

> unhashable type: list

Comment: try: `Counter(tuple(i) for i in a[0])` because you have a list with first element tuple and within which there exists  lists which needs to be converted to tuple

Comment: @Mr.A yeah, works fine,thanks, can you please take a look at the edit i've made to the question

Comment: @Mr.A  consider entries like

['7','8'] and ['8','7']

same(duplicates). and the only one entry should be in the column and frequency should be added to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [(['7', '8'], ['4', '7'],['3', '4'],['3', '8'],['4', '8'],['3','4'],['7','8'],['8','7'],['4','3'])]

frequency_list = Counter(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in a[0])

print "bigram","frequency"
for key,val in frequency_list.items():
    print key, val
```

output is as follows

```
bigram    frequency
('4', '7') 1
('4', '8') 1
('7', '8') 3
('3', '4') 3
('3', '8') 1
```

Comment: Sir, will it remove my duplicates.? eg  [7,8] and [8,7] are same, and remove [8,7] from the list but frequency added in [7,8]

Comment: thanks sir, it was just a part of my code, if you would help me in cracking this problem, it'll be really helpful
[click the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594210/create-a-bigram-from-a-column-in-pandas-df)

Comment: the output which i am getting, can i store it in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

List are not hashable to be use as the dictionary keys, you need to convert them to a hashable object. Which in this case `tuple` is a suitable choice:

```
In [5]: Counter(map(tuple, a[0])).items()
Out[5]: 
[(('4', '7'), 1),
 (('4', '8'), 1),
 (('7', '8'), 1),
 (('3', '4'), 2),
 (('3', '8'), 1)]
```

If you want to consider unordere arrays the same you have to sort them them pass them to `Counter`:

```
In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
[(['7', '8'],
  ['4', '7'],
  ['3', '4'],
  ['3', '8'],
  ['4', '8'],
  ['3', '4'],
  ['7', '4'])]

In [8]: Counter(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in a[0])
Out[8]: Counter({('4', '7'): 2, ('3', '4'): 2, ('3', '8'): 1, ('7', '8'): 1, ('4', '8'): 1})
```

**Note** that, since your numbers are string if they have more than one digit length you should convert them to integer before sorting, otherwise they'd be sorted lexicographically.

Comment: consider entries like

['7','8'] and ['8','7']

same(duplicates). and the only one entry should be in the column and frequency should be added to that.

Comment: thanks sir, it was just a part of my code, if you would help me in cracking this problem, it'll be really helpful
[click the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594210/create-a-bigram-from-a-column-in-pandas-df)

Comment: It may not be necessary to convert them to integers first, as the `sorted` function is consistent, it doesn't matter we sort `['3', '1', '2']` to `['1', '2', '3']` or `['1', '3', '2']`, only if the consistency can be guaranteed, duplicates will not exist in the final output.

Answer (score 2):

It will work using Counter if you change your list to:
`a = [('7', '8'), ... ('4', '7')]`

Or you can map your lists to tuples, because tuples are hashable but not lists.

[Update] Sort and then map each of your list to tuples first.
`Counter(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), a[0])).items()` (Based on @Kasramvd).

Comment: consider entries like

['7','8'] and ['8','7']

same(duplicates). and the only one entry should be in the column and frequency should be added to that.

Comment: Sir, will it remove the duplicate entries, as i've mentioned?

Comment: It will. You may have a try :) `sorted` function will make a list ['8', '7'] to ['7', '8'], and tuple(['7', '8']) will get ('7', '8'). @SRingne

Comment: thanks ,it was just a part of my code, if you would help me in cracking this problem, it'll be really helpful
[click the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594210/create-a-bigram-from-a-column-in-pandas-df)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `itertools.groupby` to group the sorted list of items. The key to the group can be a custom key which can create an ordered list. For a binary tuple, you can use a simple comparison to create such a tuple

Considering

```
a = [(['7', '8'], ['4', '7'],['3', '4'],['3', '8'],['4', '8'],['4','3'])]


from itertools import groupby
key = lambda tup: tup if tup[0] < tup[1] else tup[::-1]
[(key,  len(list(values))) 
 for key, values in groupby(sorted(a[0], key = key), key = key)]
Out[42]: 
[(['3', '4'], 2),
 (['3', '8'], 1),
 (['4', '7'], 1),
 (['4', '8'], 1),
 (['7', '8'], 1)]
```

If there are more than two items in a list, consider using sorted as a key. This may not be efficient but can be convenient

```
[(key,  len(list(values)))
 for key, values in groupby(sorted(a[0], key = sorted), key = sorted)]
Out[37]: 
[(['3', '4'], 2),
 (['3', '8'], 1),
 (['4', '7'], 1),
 (['4', '8'], 1),
 (['7', '8'], 1)]
```

Comment: Sir, will it remove my duplicates.? eg  [7,8] and [8,7] are same, and remove [8,7] from the list but frequency added in [7,8]

Comment: @SRingne: Yes. See my example above

Comment: thanks sir, it was just a part of my code, if you would help me in cracking this problem, it'll be really helpful
[click the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594210/create-a-bigram-from-a-column-in-pandas-df)