# Convert rows of a column in pandas df in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

i have a table in pandas df, consisting of two columns.

```
   |product_id   |Bigram
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   |111          |[('111','987'),('987','741'),('12','111')]
   |987          |[('987','1232'),('1232','987')
   |654          |('654,12'),('12,324'),('24,465')]
   |321          |[('321','741')]
   |324          |[('324','654'),('654','862'),('862','324')]
   |123          |[('123','98'),('12','123')]
```

i want to create a list L, from the Bigram column such that, all the values in each row and across every rows gets appended in the list.

for example. my output should be.

```
L = [(['987','1232'],['1232','987'],['654,12'],['12,324'],['24,465'],
['321','741'],............['123','98'],['12','123'])]
```

Is there any way to do this? using some for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I  think you need [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
L = df.Bigram.tolist()
```

Or:

```
L = list(df.Bigram)
```

EDIT:

Problem is values in column `Bigram` are strings, so first need convert to `list` of tuples by `ast`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from  itertools import chain

df.Bigram = df.Bigram.apply(literal_eval)
print (df)
   product_id                                Bigram
0         111   [(111, 987), (987, 741), (12, 111)]
1         987            [(987, 1232), (1232, 987)]
2         654     [(654, 12), (12, 324), (24, 465)]
3         321                          [(321, 741)]
4         324  [(324, 654), (654, 862), (862, 324)]
5         123                [(123, 98), (12, 123)]

L = [tuple([list(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(df.Bigram)])]
print (L)
[(['111', '987'], ['987', '741'], ['12', '111'], 
  ['987', '1232'], ['1232', '987'], ['654', '12'], 
  ['12', '324'], ['24', '465'], ['321', '741'],
  ['324', '654'], ['654', '862'], ['862', '324'], 
  ['123', '98'], ['12', '123'])]
```

Comment: this code gives me `L = [ [('987','1232'),('1232','987'),('654,12'])] , [('987','1232'),('1232','987')]`, a list inside a list, but see my output it's different

Comment: @jezrael : Nice edit. Sir, can you take a look at this once please. [jezrael question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594210/create-a-bigram-from-a-column-in-pandas-df)

Comment: @jezrael it's not working.i'ts breaking every digit and giving me output.
`L = [(['''], ['9'], ['8'], ['7'], ['''], [','], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['2'], ['''],['('], ['''], ['1'], ['2'], ['3']......and so on`

Comment: @JohnGalt it's not working.i'ts breaking every digit and giving me output.
`L = [(['''], ['9'], ['8'], ['7'], ['''], [','], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['2'], ['''],['('], ['''], ['1'], ['2'], ['3']......and so on`

Comment: Ya, I starts working for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594210/create-a-bigram-from-a-column-in-pandas-df) question, but now I see very nice answer. So I upvote it; )